# Pdf file and memory leaks

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, memory

i am just displaying a pdf file on webView. There is no issue from Product -> Analyze but few leaks on Instruments (all Responsible directory -> CORE PDF) when i double tap on pdf . That is  compulsory to remove all leaks before submitting an App on App Store?

Can any one tell me . That there is any limitations with PDF File which i used in my Resource Folders? because my designer give indexing in PDF File(by software)?

The problem is in my code or in PDF File?

my code is

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"brochure1" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webview loadRequest:request];
[webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

}

thanks

Comment: No problem in PDF just check your code or in above code there is no problem. show more code.

Answer (score -1):

according to apple.

> 2.1 Apps that crash will be rejected
>
> 2.15 "Apps larger than 20MB in size will not download over cellular networks (this is automatically prohibited by the App Store)"

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

check the file size of your product. and make sure it does not crash before submitting the app. memory leaks may cause app crash.

hope that helps :)